# Does Mass Effect: Andromeda contradict Mass Effect 3 ending?

Tags: mass-effect-series

From the transmissions in Pathfinder's logs you learn that Reapers attacked and most likely everyone in the Milky Way is dead, as there hasn't been signs of life since 2186. But doesn't this contradict Mass Effect 3 ending, where no matter which of 3 choices you make, the Milky Way is saved?

Comment: Why remove spoiler protection?

Comment: i can't speak for Frank but i did debate myself on weather that the question title implied spoilers anyway so in question spoilers wouldn't be necessary

Comment: Because a question has to make sense without the spoilers. Your entire question was spoiled. We don't dance around asking a question; just ask it. If people don't want to be spoiled, they don't have to read it.

Comment: @Frank fair enough

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIRC, no matter which ending you choose in ME3, the relay network gets destroyed.  The relay network was, among other things, responsible for interstellar communications (apart from the quantuum communication system, which was top secret, bleeding edge stuff in ME2.)  So, although life in general was saved, *civilization* - at an interstellar level - was crippled.

So, from the perspective of the Andromeda team, there wouldn't be any *signs of life* back in the Milky Way after the Reaper invasion, but that doesn't mean there's no life at all.

Comment: So basically ME3 ended similar to: Futurama:
Bender's Game where dark matter is made useless and they had to start using nibbler powered vehicles instead :-)

Answer (score 2):

Upon reading deeper into some of the logs, and also from certain conversations Ryder has with various NPC's, you learn that the Andromeda Initiative launched well *before* the events of the original trilogy occurred. Therefore once arrived in the new galaxy some 600+ years later, no one from the initiative would know what the outcome of the Milky Way conflict was.

So to answer the original question, no, it doesn't contradict the ME3 ending(s).

Answer (score -7):

My opinion.

Within the game,

There are conversations on how the Golden worlds were picked. They did an extraordinary amount of research. The Andromeda Initiative chose the world, that each pathfinder would eventually explore and colonize. Once they finally got there, all their research and theories failed.

With saying that. Within the Pathfinder's logs, as you stated in your question.

"There hasn't been signs of life since 2186"

All you know is what's in the logs. It says that there hasn't been signs of life, but how do they actually know. They really don't. More of an observation.

[Check this site out, for an interview that may help you out](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2016/12/02/how-mass-effect-3s-ending-influenced-andromeda)

Comment: i suggest you quote what parts of the link are relevant. alot of what i skimmed though just talked about production and comparisons with previous games and nothing on what explains the fate of life in the Milky Way Galaxy (which the Asker says that Andromeda implied that everyone died at the end of the third game)

Comment: I've read the linked article, and it does not answer my question at all.